# Write a query that could find the head coaches to all NBA basketball teams

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I would like to write a query that could find the head coaches to all NBA basketball teams. I wrote the following (simple) query:

```
PREFIX db: <http://dbpedia.org/>
PREFIX ex: <http://example.org/>
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

CONSTRUCT {
  ?coach ex:hasteam ?team .
} WHERE {
  ?coach dbo:team ?team 
}
```

This query provides me with the head coaches to all existing sportteams around the world. But like I mentioned before, I only need the head coaches of the NBA basketball teams. I can't seem to find out what I have to add to the query, in order to get the preferred query result.

Comment: please fix your formatting of the query first, it's unusable with the PREFIX declarations missing `< >` ...

Comment: and to find out how to process you should just look at some examples in DBpedia then, i.e. look at NBA teams and NBA coaches and check how those are related to each other. Like http://dbpedia.org/resource/Brad_Stevens and http://dbpedia.org/resource/Boston_Celtics

Comment: Thanx! I looked at how the two were related to one another, the only thing I could find is the division that both are in. I tried the following query, and it gave me the information that I wanted:                                                                                                            


CONSTRUCT {
  ?team ex:hasCoach ?coach .
    
} WHERE {
  ?team dbo:coach ?coach ;
    dbp:division ?division 
FILTER regex(?division,"NBA")  
}

Comment: your query doesn't do what you want. I mean, first of all it gives you not only NBA teams. And secondly, it also doesn't give you the current coach of a team but simply all of them.